# How can I add schema.org (primaryImageOfPage) in my site

Tags: html, google-search, schema.org

I have no idea how to add an image in Google Search.

I just want to add the image of the page in Google Search.

```
<body>
<div>
 <img height="180" src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-ARWw3b8l8RI/VQ_gW2mIHtI/AAAAAAAABQc/tuzJvua7o5Q/s1600/Bisan%2BAsa%2BKo.jpg" width="320" />
</div
</body>
```

Comment: You want to use the `primaryImageOfPage` property for the `img` from the code snippet? Did you try something? Where do you have problems?

Comment: adding schema. org data does not guarantee it will appear in google search, try adding the image to your site map, the code for the structred data code for an image can be found on http://schema.org/ImageObject

Answer (score 3):

You must use the following code:

### Method 1

```
<meta itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" content="e.g./pic.jpg" />
```

### Method 2

```
<body>
   <div itemscope itemtype="https://schema.org/WebPage">
      <img src="e.g./pic.jpg" itemprop="primaryImageOfPage" />
   </div>
</body>
```

Also referer to:

- https://schema.org/docs/gs.html
- https://schema.org/primaryImageOfPage

Comment: Thank you, this is a very simple explanation. Took me a while to find it